# How to use jQuery-UI drag and drop with two divs containing elements of identical ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have common jQuery function for drag and drop and two div tags. Both div tags have different ids but both containing elements of identical ids. 
I have a block and a placeholder for each so when i drag 'block1' olny placeholder of first table should be blink and but both are blinking. Same for block2 when i drag block2 only placeholder of second table should be blink and placeholder of first table should accept only block1 and same for placeholder of second table.I have implemented common function but it's not working. when i am dragging any block both placeholders are blinking and both placeholders are accepting the block.

Here's link to my fiddle - jsfiddle.net/2pFqe/3/

In fiddle i have two divs of id, 'id1' and 'id2' both containing elements of same id. Now when i drag block1 both placeholders are blinking.
I have tried .filter(:first), eq(0) but no solution

Is there any way to do this??

Please help me to sort out this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery wild card selector `$("[id^=block]")`

Comment: hi N K, can you elaborate your suggestion ???. Because i have tried accept:$("[id^=fourth]"), but having same issue

Comment: You have identical divs with id *div1*,*div2* etc. You can select all in one step as `$("[id^=div]")` which returns all elements with id starting with *div*. If you want to select all *li* in these you can apply $("[id^=div] li").